# run java exec command, always need full absolute path to the application?

Tags: java, macos, bash

**Environment:** `mac`

**Precondition:** I already configured `'adb'` full path to my `bash_profile`. and when I tried type `'adb'` in my terminal, it is working.

But, I tried to exec `'adb'` command from java, `'adb'` is not working, instead I need to pass the full adb path to make it work.

I guess this is probably something to do with the `bash_profile` setting,  anyone know the exact reason for this issue?

Comment: *"I tried to exec 'adb' command from java"* - How?

Comment: Where's the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` runs `/bin/sh -c <command>`. If this is or points to a bash shell on your system: A non-interactive bash does not read `.bash_profile` unless explicitly (`--login`) told to do so.

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files):

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

It's a little convoluted, but non-interactive, non-login bash instances don't read the profile files.

Your path settings does not get picked up by the subshell (which is actually `/bin/sh` which **might not even be bash at all**).

If you want, you can add the path to `adb` system wide by adding an [appropriate entry to to `/etc/paths.d`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html).